# How to tell cmake where ui file generated with autouic is

Tags: qt, cmake

I have main window class includes:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
```

Where `ui_mainwindow.h` is source file generated from `mainwindow.ui` file by cmake `AUTOUIC` option:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
```

But if I do my build in another folder called "build" and generated `ui_mainwindow.h` appears there:

```
cmake_qt_project\build\ui_mainwindow.h
```

How to fix the build to include `ui_mainwindow.h` from another directory or if there is no such possibility generating it in `src/` dir?

Also I can not include it in source file as

```
 #include "build/ui_mainwindow.h"
```

I need to keep possibility to make build in any dir I want.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. That is what i needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add your build directory to the list of directories searched for include files:

```
include_directories( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
```

Comment: Actually, `include_directories( "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}" )` is more correct. Note for those reading, this is needed only for CMake 3.7 and older. Starting with 3.8, this was "fixed".

Comment: @Lilian: Never using `add_subdirectory` myself so I only ever have the one BINARY_DIR. Correct addition, of course.